# I am getting Error as String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#

```
private string format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
DateTime fromdate = DateTime.ParseExact(GetFromScanDateTextBox.Text, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I am getting error when executing this line string was not recognized as a Valid Date Time.

I have tried this also but it not works

```
DateTime fromdate = DateTime.ParseExact(GetFromScanDateTextBox.Text, format,null);
```

Comment: What is the value of `GetFromScanDateTextBox.Text`?

Comment: maybe use `DateTime.Parse(GetFromScanDateTextBox.Text)` instead of `DateTime.ParseExact(GetFromScanDateTextBox.Text, ...)`

Comment: The value of textbox is 9/3/2013

Comment: So the textbox does not contain a time component and the format says there must be one (also there are no leading zeroes where the format expects them). What's so surprising?

Comment: so, your format is not good ...

Comment: you should remove HH:mm:ss from the format to get this to function.. if your desired input is date only..

Answer (score 3):

Your format string must be `"d/M/yyyy"`, take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Basically

**MM** : The month, from **01** through 12.

while

**M** : The month, from **1** through 12.

The same for the day part.

Comment: Thanks you very much, you just save my day :)

Answer (score 2):

You are telling `DateTime.ParseExact` that you are expecting a string with format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` but you are giving it a string with format `d/M/yyyy`.

You need to change your format to just `d/M/yyyy`.

Also I suggest using `DateTime.TryParseExact` to verify the validity of your string instead of using exceptions.

```
var okay = DateTime.TryParseExact(
               input, 
               new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "d/M/yyyy" }, 
               new CultureInfo("en-GB"), 
               DateTimeStyles.None, 
               out dateTime);
```

If your input string is liable to change, `TryParseExact` allows you to define multiple formats as shown above, or alternatively, if it is always going to be with your current culture, just do `DateTime.TryParse` and do away with defining the format.

```
var okay = DateTime.TryParse(input, out dateTime);
```

Answer (score -1):

If your format is always **month/date/year** and particularly in this case(if your date is **3rd Sept 2013**) you can use:

```
    string format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    string dateTime = "9/3/2013";
    dateTime = (dateTime.Split('/')[0].Length == 1 ? "0" + dateTime.Split('/')[0] : dateTime.Split('/')[0]) + "/" + (dateTime.Split('/')[1].Length == 1 ? "0" + dateTime.Split('/')[1] : dateTime.Split('/')[1]) + "/" + dateTime.Split('/')[2];
    DateTime fromdate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: You don't need to do this much work to parse it. Your code is also kind of messy, so it's hard to understand. Also, the example date has the day before the month. See the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

Do not provide the HH:MM:SS part in the format part

string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
DateTime fromdate = DateTime.ParseExact(test.Text, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: I don't think this will work since your format is expecting double-digit days and months, whereas the example date given uses single-digits.

Comment: The person who posted the question indicated in a comment on the question that that is not the case.